# htaccess condition not working on godaddy host

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

My .htaccess on localhost XAMPP works fine;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/templates/$1\.tpl -f
RewriteRule ^([\w\-.\s]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /sources/404.php
```

When I move it to GoDaddy host, when I'm trying to go site.com/Downloads I'm getting error 404 which doesn't happen on XAMPP.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, most likely those rules do not get applied there.

Comment: @arkascha so what is the alternative for RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/templates/$1\.tpl -f?

Comment: Finding out why the rule does not get applied and changing that.

Comment: @arkascha any help on how I should debug it? I googled it, and it's a few hours for now that I'm looking for a solution on google :P 
%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} is a relative path and not absolute and I'm guessing that is the problem

Comment: @arkascha I found the reason, seems it's with case-sensitive, any way to do it ignore case-sensitive? so Download and download will work? its a GoDaddy host which runs on Linux server.

Comment: I'm guessing you are testing on Windows (case insensitive OS) and the underlying file is perhaps `download`, not `Download`? The "problem" is not with your rule, but with the underlying OS.